# How can I rewrite the body of an email I have received in Outlook without using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a number of informational emails containing department ID numbers. Recently, a corporate-level decision was made to alter ALL of these ID numbers. However, SOME departments have decided that they won't bother to use the new numbers when issuing these informational emails, much to our chagrin.

Until corporate starts enforcing the new rules, when I receive an email from these non-compliant departments, I'd like to be able to insert the new ID number beside the old one in the email body, without creating a new email. For preference, I'd like to do this without VBA, in much the same way as [changing the subject line](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-an-email-subject-line-08d60328-2a27-473e-8227-0b42a1ff2ce6). The side-effect of the visible difference between what was sent and what I want to read would actually be very helpful.

That article says it's possible to alter the body, but doesn't say how. I'll be darned if I can find anything about altering the body of received emails, other than formatting.

Is it possible to do this without VBA? How would I do so?

Comment: I'd just reply and say that you don't recognize the ID number till they get it right. The best way is to fix the issue at its source.

Comment: @K.Davis Indeed, this strategy has been discussed at this end, and we *SHALL NOT* (emphasis not mine) be pursuing such a direction. Politics and bureaucracy are not fun.

Comment: Are you just asking how to edit a received email  in outlook?  It's pretty straightforward: Message Ribbon >> Actions >> edit message.   Save and close when done.

Comment: If you want these "inserts or replacements" to be done automatically ("hands off") by outlook, you are going to need VBA my friend.

Comment: @Tim Williams, yes, that's exactly what I mean. I know it had to be there, but I couldn't find the option and Google kept getting subverted by ways to charge the subject line (arrrghghgh). It's so aggravating when you can't discover basic menu items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body.

If you still want to do that manually, see the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, it needs to be manual. Because some of the ID numbers are being recycled into other, different departments and will still be in use, it is occasionally the context of WHY I'm being sent an email that determines wheter the number is being used to identify the old or new department.